# How to write script output to file and command-line?

Tags: python, unix, command-line

I have a long-running Python script that I run from the command-line. The script writes progress messages and results to the standard output. I want to capture everything the script write to the standard output in a file, but also see it on the command line. Alternatively, I want the output to go to the file immediately, so I can use `tail` to view the progress. I have tried this:

```
python MyLongRunngingScript.py | tee log.txt
```

But it does not produce any output (just running the script produces output as expected). Can anyone propose a simple solution? I am using Mac OS X 10.6.4.

**Edit** I am using `print` for output in my script.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are on the right path but the problem is python buffering the output.

Fortunately there is a way to tell it not to buffer output:

```
python -u MyLongRunngingScript.py | tee log.txt
```

Comment: Don't forget to redirect the ``stderr`` stream to ``stdout`` if you also want to capture that: ``python -u MyLongRunngingScript.py 2>&1 | tee log.txt``

Answer (score 2):

The fact that you don't see anything is probably related to the fact that buffering is occurring. So you only get output every 4 Ko of text or so.

instead, try something like this :

```
class OutputSplitter(object):
    def __init__(self, real_output, *open_files):
        self.__stdout = real_output
        self.__fds = open_files
        self.encoding = real_output.encoding
    def write(self, string):
        self.__stdout.write(string) # don't catch exception on that one.
        self.__stdout.flush()
        for fd in self.__fds:
            try:
                fd.write(string)
                fd.flush()
            except IOError:
                pass # do what you want here. 
    def flush(self):
        pass # already flushed
```

Then decorate sys.stdout with that class with some code like that :

```
stdout_saved = sys.stdout
logfile = open("log.txt","a") # check exception on that one.
sys.stdout = OutputSplitter(stdout_saved, logfile)
```

That way, every output (`print` included) is flushed to the standard output and to the specified file. Might require tweaking because i haven't tested that implementation.

Of course, expect to see a (small most of the time) performance penalty when printing messages.

Answer (score 2):

Another simple solution could also be

```
python script.py > output.log
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try doing `sys.stdout.flush()` occasionally in your script, and running with `tee` again. When `stdout` is redirected through to `tee`, it might get buffered for longer than if it's going straight to a terminal.